# Command for detecting coordinates of a player then granting said player night vision

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to figure out a command that detects if any player is on a certain coordinate, or in the vicinity of it, and if a player is detected, it gives them night vision. What do I do to get this to work?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Arqade. Could you share some commands (or attempts) that you tried and did not work? That would really help with pointing you in the right direction.

Comment: @Gigazelle well that's the thing, I don't know where to start, I haven't been able to try anything

Comment: If that's the case, I'd highly recommend learning the basics of commands so you can start getting the hang of making more complex stuff like this. This would be an excellent starting point: https://www.howtogeek.com/226078/the-beginners-guide-to-command-blocks-in-minecraft/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Bytes1024 had a good idea in his answer, but wrongly executed. The command you are looking for is this:

```
/execute positioned <coordinates> run effect give @a[distance=..<radius>] <effect> <time> <amplification>
```

Substitute `<coordinates>` with the coordinates you want, and substitute `<radius>` with the radius you want the command to detect players in, `<effect>` with the effect you want to give, `<time>` with how many seconds you want it to last, and `<amplification>` with how many levels you want to add to the effect.

So, if you want to give a player at coordinates 32 68 338 in the radius of 1 the effect night vision 1 for 100 seconds, it would look like this:

```
/execute positioned 32 68 338 run effect give @a[distance=..1] minecraft:night_vision 100 0
```

Comment: Its saying    Syntax error: Unexpected "run" at "32 68 338 >>run<< effect gi"

Comment: Ok, I'll try and figure it out

Comment: thank you for helping with this 

Comment: That's what this site is all about, glad I could help :) Also, I edited the post to the correct state.

Comment: it's still saying the same thing, also I should mention that I'm on console, idk if that changes anything or not

Comment: here is my code: /execute positioned 32 68 338 run effect give @a [distance=.. 1]

Comment: @TrazmaballGysterMyster sorry about that! I missed a crucial component of the command, giving the effect itself! Make sure you don't have any unnecessary spaces between components of the command (write `@a[distance=..1]` instead of `@a [distance= ..1]`).

Comment: oh no man it's cool, and again thank you for the help!  I'll try the command out as soon as I have the chance

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

`/effect give @a[x={your x coordinate},y={your y coordinate},z={your z coordinate},r={the radius from the coordinates}] night_vision {length in seconds} true`

(Don't put the `{` and `}`)

**EDIT:**
As user Quijibo pointed out, `r` doesn't seem to work in 1.13 (I didn't know that), so does `/effect give @a[x={your x coordinate},y={your y coordinate},z={your z coordinate},dx={final x coordinate},dy={final y coordinate},dz={final z coordinate}] true` work?

It checks for players within the `x`,`y`,`z` to `dx`,`dy`,`dz` box.

Comment: But `r=` doesn't work in 1.13.